# amazon-ivs-player with Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, npm, video-streaming

I am trying to use the npm version of the amazon-ivs-player with Angular.

It seems to have been designed for use with webpack.. but of course I am stuck with the angular-cli.

I am following this example:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-player-web-sample/blob/master/samples/npm-sdk/npm-sdk.ts

Angular-cli does not seem to like the two import statement for the wasm files:
import wasmBinaryPath from 'amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm'
import wasmWorkerPath from 'amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.js';

I get these errors when trying to compile the application:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/player2/video-player.component.ts 48:43-57
"export 'default' (imported as 'wasmBinaryPath') was not found in 'amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm'
ERROR in ./node_modules/amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'a' in 'C:\Users\james\demo\ui\node_modules\amazon-ivs-player\dist\assets'

ERROR in ./node_modules/amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm
WebAssembly module is included in initial chunk.
This is not allowed, because WebAssembly download and compilation must happen asynchronous.
Add an async splitpoint (i. e. import()) somewhere between your entrypoint and the WebAssembly module:
multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./src/main.ts --> ./src/main.ts --> ./src/app/app.module.ts --> ./src/app/components/player2/video-player.component.ts --> ./node_modules/amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm
```

Is there anyone that could shed any light on this?

Maybe there is another way to use wasm with the Angular framework?

If I cant use npm then maybe I have to use the script tags but then I dont think I can interact with the Angular code in the application.

Kind regards
J

```
// vjs-player.component.ts
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import videojs from 'video.js';

import {
    registerIVSTech,
    registerIVSQualityPlugin,
    VideoJSQualityPlugin,
    VideoJSIVSTech,
    VideoJSEvents,
    create,
    ErrorType,
    isPlayerSupported,
    MediaPlayer,
    PlayerError,
    PlayerEventType,
    PlayerState,
    Quality,
    TextCue,
    TextMetadataCue
} from 'amazon-ivs-player';

// We use the TypeScript compiler (TSC) to check types; it doesn't know what this WASM module is, so let's ignore the error it throws (TS2307).
// @ts-ignore
import wasmBinaryPath from 'amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.wasm';
import wasmWorkerPath from 'amazon-ivs-player/dist/assets/amazon-ivs-wasmworker.min.js';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-vjs-player',
    template: `
  <video #target class="video-js" width=960 height=540 controls muted playsinline preload="none"></video>`,
    styleUrls: [
        './video-player.component.css'
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('target', { static: true }) target: ElementRef;
    // see options: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/maintutorial-options.html
    @Input() options: {
        fluid: boolean,
        aspectRatio: string,
        autoplay: boolean,
        sources: {
            src: string,
            type: string,
        }[],
    };
    player: videojs.Player;
    url: string;
        constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
    ) { }


    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const createAbsolutePath = (assetPath: string) => new URL(assetPath, document.URL).toString();
        
        const player = videojs('videojs-player', {
            techOrder: ["AmazonIVS"]
        });
        //registerIVSTech(videojs, options);

        // Set up IVS playback tech and quality plugin
        registerIVSTech(videojs, {
            wasmWorker: createAbsolutePath(wasmWorkerPath),
            wasmBinary: createAbsolutePath(wasmBinaryPath),
        });
        registerIVSQualityPlugin(videojs);

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    }
}
```

Any pointers really appreciated.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: hi... did you solved the problem ? I am also facing same issue here..

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working I had to use the @angular-builders/custom-webpack with file-loader to load the wasm file after the transpiler.

I added this config into my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /[\/\\]amazon-ivs-player[\/\\].*dist[\/\\]assets[\/\\]/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                type: 'javascript/auto',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'static/ivs-player',
                    publicPath: 'static/ivs-player'
                }
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

and changed my angular.json to have:

```
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "customWebpackConfig": {
                            "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
                            "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
                        },
```

and

```
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
```